How can I install the latest version of PEAR?
After reading this Q&A I'm still stuck at PEAR v1.10.13 which contains a number of conflicts with the default php version (8.3.6) on Ubuntu 24.  At the time of this question the latest stable PEAR version is 1.10.15 which seems to have those conflicts resolved.
I tried:
pear channel-update pear.php.net
pear upgrade-all

Which left me unchanged at version 1.10.13. I then tried the "easy install" command from the download page with the following result:
$ pear install PEAR-1.10.15
Failed to download pear/Archive_Tar (recommended version 1.4.4), latest release is version 1.5.0, stability "stable", use "channel://pear.php.net/Archive_Tar-1.5.0" to install
WARNING: "pear/Console_Getopt" is deprecated in favor of "pear/Console_GetoptPlus"
pear/PEAR dependency package "pear/Archive_Tar" installed version 1.4.14 is not the recommended version 1.4.4, but may be compatible, use --force to install
No valid packages found
install failed

I can probably just download it directly but I'd be concerned about it possibly being overwritten in the future. Why doesn't pear upgrade-all have the desired effect? Can someone recommend the best way to update pear to the latest stable version?

I'm no expert on this but what worked for me was running the following commands:
$ wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
$ php go-pear.phar

This updated to the latest version then I ran the normal commands to install mail and the other relevant packages.

Thanks - I'm not actually sure what I did because it was a couple of months ago, but somehow I got it working before so can't test your suggestion.

Since I just stumbled upon similar problem and was able to resolve it here's quick and easy solution:

Clean cache and update package list:
pear clear-cache
pear update-channels


Install required dependency package Archive_Tar manually:
pear install --force Archive_Tar


Upgrade pear:
pear upgrade --force PEAR


(optional step) List installed packages, upgrade-able packages and perform upgrade:
pear list
pear list-upgrades
pear upgrade

In case of dependency failure just install it manually, as shown in #2.


NOTE 1: Don't forget to restart your php-fpm and httpd services - if have them installed!
NOTE 2: The "ultimate" test for any php module: php -m. If the module is listed it was installed/upgraded successfully.
